# Only use 1 collider of my gameobject when using OnCollisionEnter2D() Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, collider

#### Hello

so i am having a little problem with my ontriggerenter script:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "ground")
        {
            Cground = true;
            jumping = false;
            animator.SetBool("jumping", jumping);
            Debug.Log(Cground);
        }
        Debug.Log("touch");
        Debug.Log("Touched! " + other.gameObject.name + "; " + other.gameObject.tag + "; " + Cground);

    }
```

this is what i have so far but i only want the code in the if statement to g off when i collide with the edgecollider on my gameobject. i currently have 2 different colliders on this gameobject an edge collider and a polygon collider. none of the code in the if statement should be triggered when the polygon collider collides with something.
im happy for any help i can get.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html) and be sure you meet all the requirements for the collision detection there explained.

Typicall mistace is to miss the rigidbody component. From the docs:

Note: Trigger events are only sent if one of the Colliders also has a Rigidbody2D attached. Trigger events are sent to disabled MonoBehaviours, to allow enabling Behaviours in response to collisions.

Once checked that you are complying with everything in the docs, if you do still have problems, you would need to share the gameObject components of the two gameibjects involved collision.